# Scala group on named Tuple to get min value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Seq of Named tuples as follows:

Seq[GeoDetails] where GeoDetails is of the type `GeoDetails(geo_name: String, first_geo_time: Long)`

In the Sequence, there can be multiple records for a single Geo and I want to write a function to Group by on geo_name and take the MIN value for first_geo_time. For e.g.

**Input**:

```
Seq(GeoDetails("cn", 1111111111111L), GeoDetails("mx", 2222222222222L), GeoDetails("mx", 3333333333333L), GeoDetails("cn", 4444444444444L))
```

**Desired Output**:

```
Seq(GeoDetails("cn", 1111111111111L), GeoDetails("mx", 2222222222222L))
```

I think using groupBy and foldLeft can do the job but I'm new to Scala and would appreciate some help on this. I want to get the output with the case class being maintained

Comment: Using only Scala  or your question is how to do it in Spark?

Comment: `.groupBy(_.geo_name).values.map(_.minBy(_.first_geo_time))`

Comment: I'm trying to do it in a Spark flow written in Scala. This is one of the columns generated in a group by statement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (Scala 2.13):

```
 val list = Seq(GeoDetails("cn", 1111111111111L), GeoDetails("mx", 2222222222222L), GeoDetails("mx", 3333333333333L), GeoDetails("cn", 4444444444444L))

 list.groupBy(_.geo_name).view.mapValues(el => el.sortBy(_.first_geo_time).head).toList
```

Comment: This returns a different output tuple
Seq((mx, GeoDetails(mx,2222222222222)),(cn, GeoDetails(cn,1111111111111)))
@jwvh's comment on the question does the job